# Prove that $S = \{a^2 + b^2: a,b \in \Bbb N\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Is it true?

Can you prove or disprove this?

$S = \{a^2 + b^2: a,b \in \Bbb N\}$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: This isn't a homework site. Share your work/thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Here's a related article with an interesting generalisation and proofs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Comment: Does your $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$?

Comment: @BrianTung why do you ask, it shouldn't matter for this problem.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Doesn't it?  $2 = 1^2+1^2$ is in $S$ under either interpretation, but $2 \times 2 = 4$ is only a sum of squares if zero is a square.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elementary number theory, sums of two squares](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520792/elementary-number-theory-sums-of-two-squares)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that $x=a^2+b^2$ and $y=c^2+d^2$. Then

$$xy=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\-b&a
\end{pmatrix}
\det\begin{pmatrix}
c&d\\-d&c
\end{pmatrix}
=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\-b&a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c&d\\-d&c
\end{pmatrix}
=\det\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a c-b d & b c+a d \\
 -b c-a d & a c-b d \\
\end{array}
\right)=(ac-bd)^2+(bc+ad)^2$$

Answer (score 6):

Write

> $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2.$$

This comes from me knowing that $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi) = |a+bi|^2|$. Here $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Then I just multiply $(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$, and since

> $$|zw|^2=|z|^2|w|^2$$

So that means we know that $(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2=|(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)|^2=|a+bi|^2|c+di|^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$.

Comment: is this enough ?can you explain for me?

Comment: @MustafaUmutKazancıoğlu: If this isn't enough, perhaps you should review what it means for a set $S$ to be closed under some operation (in this case, multiplication).  It means, in short, that given elements $x, y \in S$, their product $xy$ is inevitably in $S$ also.  Isn't that exactly what this answer demonstrates?